# 100% page height using JS not working on certain pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a strange problem where the middle section of some of the pages aren't stretching to 100% page height, wihch results in there not being the full left hand border.

Here for example (please click on the 'Brentwood' link and go to 'Login' on the top menu) https://www.inside-guides.co.uk/advertiseradmin/default.asp?.

Whereas the 'Contact' page is fine (again via the 'Brentwood' site): https://www.inside-guides.co.uk/feedback.asp.

They both use the same template using javascript and CSS, but when I look in the code inspector it gives full page height values for the #left-nav and #middle on the 'Contact'page which works.

The javascript is to make each column the same height = i.e. to the top of the footer, but it doesn't work on the Login page.

I really can't understand why so any help perhaps using a code inspector would be very much appreciated.

JS code placed in the head.css on each page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
matchColumns=function(){ 
     var divs,contDivs,maxHeight,divHeight,d; 
     divs=document.getElementsByTagName('div'); 
     contDivs=[]; 
     maxHeight=0;  
     for(var i=0;i<divs.length;i++){  
          // make collection with <div> elements with class attribute "equal"
          if(/\bequal\b/.test(divs[i].className)){ 
                d=divs[i]; 
                contDivs[contDivs.length]=d;  
                if(d.offsetHeight){ 
                     divHeight=d.offsetHeight;                  
                } 
                else if(d.style.pixelHeight){ 
                     divHeight=d.style.pixelHeight;                  
                } 
                maxHeight=Math.max(maxHeight,divHeight); 
          } 
     } 
     for(var i=0;i<contDivs.length;i++){ 
          contDivs[i].style.height=maxHeight + "px"; 
     } 
}  
window.onload=function(){ 
     if(document.getElementsByTagName){ 
          matchColumns();            
     } 
} 
</script>
```

Login page code where the 100% JS page height isn't working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!--#include virtual="/System/Startup_FranchiseClient.asp"-->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<%
EnsurePageIsHTTPS
If IsFranchiseClientLoggedIn = True then
Response.Redirect GetAdvertiserAdminHomePage
End if
%>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Inside-Guides.co.uk - Advertiser Login</title>
<!--#include virtual="/Assets/Templates/Public/Franchise/HeadCSS.asp"-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/common.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.cycle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="login" onload="javascript:document.getElementById('strUsername').focus();">
<!--#include virtual="/Assets/Templates/Public/Franchise/TemplateStart_https.asp"-->
<div class="content clearfix">
<div id="form" class="form">
<h1>Advertiser Login</h1>
<p>Welcome to the advertiser area.  Please enter your login details below:</p>
<span class="ErrorText"><% = strSecurity_LoginError %></span>
<form id="form" name="LoginForm" method="post" action="Default.asp">
<input type="hidden" name="ValidateLogin" value="1" />
<label>Email
<span class="small">Email used to register</span>
</label>
<input type="text" id="strUsername" name="strUsername" value="" />
<br />
<label>Password
<span class="small">Password used to register</span>
</label>
<input type="password" name="strPassword" value="" />
<button type="submit">Log-in</button>
<div class="spacer"></div>
</form>
</div>
<p> * If you have forgotten your password, please <a href="ForgotPassword.asp">click here</a></p>
</div>
<!--#include virtual="/Assets/Templates/Public/Franchise/TemplateEnd.asp"-->
</body>
</html>
<!--#include virtual="/System/Shutdown.asp"-->
```

CSS:

```
#middle {padding-top:7px;float:left;width:60%;border-right:1px solid #edeaec;border-left:1px solid #ede9e8;}
#middle.dir {width:78.5%;border-right:0;}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you got this in your CSS: body, html { height:100% }; ?

Comment: Yep, but it doesn't work so I'm using the javascript. Any ideas?  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> JS code placed in the head.css on each page

Not sure if this is a typo or not, but if it isn't you cannot place js in a css file. Also no css file seems to be linked in the head of you html document.
**However on further inspection it seems you are referring to the headCSS.asp template include in which case the above point isn't of concern.**

For height `100%` or any percentage based heights the parent must have a defined height, making it essentially not very useful because you need to know height values anyway. So if you can set it to a fixed height that would be my suggestion.

*Answer*
However I suggest a `<table>` to do what you're looking with a single row and multiple columns, using one will avoid a lot of hacky css and or js.